# $A\neq \varnothing $, $B\neq \varnothing$, $A\neq B.$ Prove $A\times B \neq B\times A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

> $$A\neq \varnothing ,B\neq \varnothing,A\neq B. \\\text{Prove }A\times B \neq B\times A$$

I'm pretty sure this has to do with inverse for relations. But I'm not sure how to begin proofing something like this. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Are we defining $(x,y)=\{x,\{y\}\}$?

Comment: **Hint:** $A=\{0,1\}$, $B=\{0\}$. Then $A\times B=\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$ and $B\times A=\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$

Comment: @matt: The exact definition shouldn't matter, as long as whatever definition of $A\times B$ that is used has the required universal properties.

Comment: @MJD if the only thing that is important is the universal properties, then they aren't actually different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume that there is $x\in A$, $x\notin B$. 
$B$ is not empty, so there is $y\in B$.

Then $(x,y)\in A\times B$ and $(x,y)\notin B\times A$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Since $A\neq B$, there is some $a\in A$ such that $a\notin B$, or there is some $b\in B$ such that $b\notin A$. Assume that the first case holds. Since $B$ is not empty, there is some $b\in B$. Now you have two elements from $A$ and $B$, use them to produce a witness for the inequality you are trying to prove.